# animate an image from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image of a little tree and I would like to make it grow from *bottom* to *top* using jQuery and CSS.

For the moment the tree has `bottom` position to 0 and goes up with `animate()` jQuery function.

I can make a `div` that overlaps to the tree and animate it with `animate()` jquery function and removing the `height` to it, but the original background (of the `body`) uses a CSS gradient so I can't make the `div` overlap the image.
Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.wrap_tree{
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.tree{
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    bottom:0px;
    width:200px;
    left:28%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap_tree">
    <div class="tree">
        <img src="tree.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('.tree').animate({
    height: 'toggle'
},5000);
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff was pretty easy, he wanted a tree growing effect ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien lol, by tree i was thinking something like a treeview, shame on me ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff ha ha nope, he said animate from bottom to top so I got that he wanted to achieve tree growing effect ;)

Answer (score 6):

How about doing this with Pure CSS? I made it from scratch using CSS3 `@keyframe`

Explanation: Am just overlapping the tree using an `absolute` positioned element, and than using `@keyframe` am collapsing the `height` property to `0`, rest is self explanatory.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/1/) *(Added `position: relative;` to the container element as this is important to do else your `position: absolute;` element will run out in the wild)*

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/2/) *Tweaking up `animation-duration` for slower animation rate*

```
.tree {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.tree > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: hello;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: hello;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.tree img {
    max-width: 100%;
}



@keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
```

Comment: No sorry, there is a problem :/
can I make .tree>div transparent? Because on the gradiant css background I see the animation with a white box.. See here please: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/4/

Comment: @user3340590 you could edit jsfiddle to add the 'gradiant css background' you are talking about

Comment: @user3340590 just use the same gradient on the overlay element like Wolff suggested

Comment: @user3340590 Wait, I'll provide another way to achieve that

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you! EDIT: If you want, you can use this **very** simple png image http://i60.tinypic.com/33da238.png

Comment: @user3340590 I can fix this for you in few hours as am at office, by the time, this is dirty, but I was saying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/19/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Don't worry and thank you very much! Make this when you have free time :)
I should probably keep the background "fixed", and apply the gradient at the end of the effect, it could be a simple work around. What do you think?

Comment: @user3340590 that seems good option as well, just make sure you resize the element at the rate which your gradient repeats :) *in height*, and take out the `width` from `.tree`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div><img src="image03.png" /></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s linear 2s infinite alternate; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:0px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:0px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```